# Taylor's Inequality: defining an interval

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation

Question

> Using Taylor's Inequality, find how many terms of the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$ you need to use to estimate $\ln 1.4$ to within $0.001$?

I have found that $|f^{n+1}(x)|=\frac{n!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$

I need to find the upper bound on $|f^{n+1}(x)|$ or in other words the upper bound on the second, third, fourth... derivatives (because $n$ starts from $1$ and goes to infinity). This upper bound is called $M$. So I am trying to find $M$ such that $|f^{n+1}(x)|\leq M$. Most importantly, we need to define an interval of $x$ so that $M$ has meaning. This interval is $-d\leq x\leq d$ where $d$ is a positive number. This is where I get confused. What is $d$ in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Taylor series is centered at $1$.  You want to evaluate $\ln(1 + 0.4)$, so you want your estimate to be good out to a radius of $0.4$ from the center, so your estimate will be good for all $x$ with $1 - 0.4 \leq x \leq 1 + 0.4$.

I also note that each of your derivatives, $f^{(n)}$, is decreasing in $x$ on this interval, so each of them is bounded by their value at the left end of the interval, that is, at $x = 1-0.4 = 0.6$.  (You know that the graph of $1/x^{n+1}$ decreases on $(0, \infty)$.  Shifting it left and scaling it vertically by a positive number doesn't change that.)

Comment: why does wanting to evaluate $\ln (1+0.4)$ mean that I want my estimate to be good out to a radius of $0.4$?

Comment: @user532874 : Because $1+0.4$ is only $0.4$ units from the center $1$.  Draw a circle, centered at $1$.

Comment: What is the intuition for this?

Comment: @user532874 : Really.  It's "draw a circle".  Your Taylor series is centered at $1$ (because you are taking powers of $1+x$, so $x$ is just measuring displacement from $1$).  Then draw a circle with radius $0.4$ with the same center.  This circle encompasses the part of the real line between $1-0.4$ and $1+0.4$.

Comment: I guess this is where I am confused. When you say "so your estimate will be good for all $x$ with..." I don't get that. My estimate is only for $x=0.4$. I don't care about the other $x$ values.

Comment: @user532874 : A proper Taylor series approximation scheme uses the worst (largest) value of the next derivative *anywhere* inside the circle.  A large next derivative anywhere inside the circle forces a large error bound, even if such a large derivative only happens on the other side of the circle.  However, this gives an error bound that is valid for the entire circle, not just one point in it.

Comment: Isn't a maclaurin series centered at 0?

Comment: @user532874 : A Maclaurin series centers $x$ at zero.  You are not passing $x$ to the logarithm.  You are passing $1+x$.  The Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$ is the Taylor series of $\ln x$ centered at $1$.  We can still make exactly the same argument about radius and where to find the largest value of the next derivative for the radius $0.4$ circle.